# Netty datagram channel thread safety

Tags: netty

Can I call from different threads in Netty 4 method of io.netty.channel.Channel ?

```
    channel.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(content), to));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netty is designed with thread-safety in mind.

### Calling `channel.writeAndFlush` from a netty thread:

The current thread will follow the pipeline to the decoders and directly call its native async write and flush methods. This can be seen that the future the `writeAndFlush` is done as soon as the method returns.

### Calling `channel.writeAndFlush` from another thread:

The call will be scheduled on the netty thread in the background, and the future that `writeAndFlush` will complete on the netty thread in the background.