# Are netty channel pool operations thread safe?

Tags: netty, pool

I am working on using netty's FixedChannelPool to maintain concurrent connections. Since multiple threads will be accessing the channel pool, I was wondering if the operations acquire() and release(channel) are thread safe?

TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netty datagram channel threadsafity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627619/netty-datagram-channel-threadsafity)

Comment: The other question talks about channel.writeAndFlush's thread safety. Where as my question is whether the acquire and release methods of a channel pool are thread safe.

Comment: The answer is basicly the same, [the source](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/channel/pool/FixedChannelPool.html#200) of acquire uses the same logic to check for threads

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment in FixedChannelPool about this question: 

  `// There is no need to worry about synchronization as everything that modified the queue or counts is done by the above EventExecutor.`

But I think this is not thread-safe, because the connect promise can be added to taskQueue of any eventloop thread. If the connect promise of the same key added to taskQueue of two different eventloop, when they are executed by the eventloop, this will lead to a non-thread safe circumstance, which means if you set max number of channel to 1, if you call acquire concurrently, you may create 2 channels.

Please point out if I make a mistake on comprehending these logic.